# Prove the combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, summation-method

For any $n$ prove the following identity
$$
\sum_{i+j+k=n} j \binom{n}{i,j,k} a_{2i+1,2j-1,2k}=\sum_{i+j+k=n} i \binom{n}{i,j,k} a_{2i-1,2j+1,2k},
$$
here $$\binom{n}{i,j,k}=\frac{n!}{i! j! k!}, $$
is the multinomial coefficient, $i, j, k \geq 0.$

For small $n=1,2$ I can do it  by direct calculation but what about arbitrary $n?$

Comment: There's probably a recursion relation you can take advantage of?

Comment: Do you mean that the left and right sides satisfied the same recurrence relations? Probably, but how to find the relation?

Comment: exists coefficients with negative index as $a_{-1,3,2}$ or $a_{7,-1,4}$?

Comment: @Masacroso No, of cource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{i+j+k = n} j\binom{n}{i,j,k}a_{2i+1,2j-1,2k}
&= \sum_{\substack{i+j+k = n \\ j > 0}} j\binom{n}{i,j,k}a_{2i+1,2j-1,2k} \\
&= \sum_{\substack{i+j+k = n \\ j > 0}} n\binom{n-1}{i,j-1,k}a_{2i+1,2j-1,2k} \\
&= \sum_{i + \ell + k = n-1} n \binom{n-1}{i,\ell,k} a_{2i+1,2\ell+1,2k} \tag{$\ell = j-1$}\\
&= \sum_{\substack{m + \ell + k = n \\ m > 0}} n\binom{n-1}{m-1,\ell,k} a_{2m-1,2\ell+1,2k} \tag{$m = i+1$}\\
&= \sum_{m + \ell + k = n} m\binom{n}{m,\ell,k} a_{2m-1,2\ell+1,2k} \\
&= \sum_{i + j + k = n} i\binom{n}{i,j,k} a_{2i-1,2j+1,2k}\,. \tag{$i = m, j = \ell$}
\end{align}